# MS SQL round on whole numbers during inserting | VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have created a table...

```
"CREATE TABLE ImportantProcessParameters ([id] int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL," & _
                "[lot] varchar(19) NOT NULL UNIQUE," & _
                "[product] varchar(19) NOT NULL," & _
                "[assay] decimal(10,5)," & _
                "[fpy] decimal(10,5)," & _
                "[na] int," & _
                "[molar_ratio] decimal(10,5));"
```

and I insert data from an excel table using vba code.
The problem is in `molar ratio` column, in the excel table I have 8.40 but in SQL this number is 8.00 or if I have 3.42 in SQL it is 3.00. Code that sends data to SQL is bellow

```
"IF EXISTS (SELECT lot FROM ImportantProcessParameters WHERE lot = " & exLot & ") " & _
"UPDATE ImportantProcessParameters SET product = '" & Empty2Null(exProduct) & "', assay =  " & Empty2Null(exAssay) & ", fpy = " & Empty2Null(exFpy) & ", na = " & Empty2Null(exNa) & ", molar_ratio = " & Empty2Null(exMR) & " WHERE lot = " & exLot & " ELSE " & _
"INSERT INTO ImportantProcessParameters (lot, product, assay, fpy, na, molar_ratio) " & _
"VALUES(" & Empty2Null(exLot) & ", '" & Empty2Null(exProduct) & "', " & Empty2Null(exAssay) & ", " & Empty2Null(exFpy) & ", " & Empty2Null(exNa) & ", " & Empty2Null(exMR) & ");"
```

also i have function to sent null if excel cell is empty

```
Function Empty2Null(oValue As Variant) As String
        If oValue = Empty Then
            Empty2Null = "null"
        Else
            Empty2Null = oValue
        End If
End Function
```

Comment: What is `Empty2Null`? Also, what kind of SQL (Oracle, MS SQL, etc.)?  What happens if you try NUMERIC, FLOAT, or REAL?  What about not specifying the precision and scale?

Comment: I have some edits on the question... empty2null is function that send null if i have empty cell in excel... MS SQL is used

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can one set parameter values of an INSERT SQL query through VBA in Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810843/how-can-one-set-parameter-values-of-an-insert-sql-query-through-vba-in-microsoft)

Comment: What happens when `exProduct` contains a single quote character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in defining of the variables.

exMR was defined as Integer, not as Variant.